# Google app engine local server won't run on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, localhost

My app engine standard application was running till this morning and suddenly it won't run throwing the following error.

```
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value '/Users/sharon/Library/Application Support/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/LATEST/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/config/sdk/logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from '/Users/sharon/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/Lily/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml'
2023-10-12 17:45:17.863:INFO::main: Logging initialized @768ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2023-10-12 17:45:17.936:WARN:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Ignoring deprecated socket close linger time
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/apphosting/runtime/SessionStore
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerClassLoader.loadClass(DevAppServerClassLoader.java:117)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SessionManagerHandler.create(SessionManagerHandler.java:75)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:360)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:293)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:42)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:102)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:118)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:280)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:57)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:229)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:227)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:381)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:58)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:239)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:230)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.apphosting.runtime.SessionStore
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerClassLoader.loadClass(DevAppServerClassLoader.java:117)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 28 more
```

I don't understand what the error means. What could be the reason? I noticed that it is happening after I upgraded the gcloud sdk version to 45.0.0 but I created another app engine standard application and it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a bug or regression in cloud sdk 450.0.0 released 2023-10-10
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes

Specifically:

> App Engine Updated the Java SDK to version 2.0.20 build from the open
> source project

We were able to get local dev server working by pinning the cloudSdk version in our build.gradle file:

```
appengine {
    // Configure the Cloud SDK version
    tools {
        cloudSdkVersion = '449.0.0'
    }
...etc
```

Comment: Same problem for us when starting the "Local dev server" (exact same exception as OP) with SDK v450 and no issue at all with v449. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's exactly what I was looking for. Accepted the answer too!!

Answer (score 1):

Just got this problem today, it was working yesterday until I made a new deployment where google cloud update itself to version 450.

I move back to 449 in my pom:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>

            <configuration>
                ..
                ..
                ..

                <!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
                <cloudSdkVersion>449.0.0</cloudSdkVersion>
    
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Perform a update or make a deploy.

Then, in Eclipse, go to Windows -> Preferences -> Google Cloud Tools and Change SDK to 449 path.

Answer (score 0):

For others who might have this problem IntelliJ with gcloud installed locally (via homebrew), I had to do this:

- gcloud components update --version 449.0.0
- gcloud components install app-engine-java
- in intellij - Intellij Menu -> Settings -> Cloud Code -> Dependencies , switch ‘use a custom local installation’ to ‘/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/’, it should say ‘Cloud SDK Version 449.0.0’ if successful